# C# alternative to setpixel

Tags: c#, gdi+, getpixel

I have read through several articles which are alternatives to using setpixel/getpixel but I am not seeing how they relate to my issue.

I have a multicoloured image which (depending on dynamic values taken from DB) changes the color of each pixel color group to a new color.

Lets say I want all pixels with Argb value of -989556 changed to -16 & all pixels with Argb value of -1331 changed to -5383962.
I am currently looking at every pixel in the Bitmap and checking their value, if they match then they are changed using setpixel.

I am sure there must be a better way but I am being too dim to see it!

Comment: What is the problem you have doing it using GetPixel()/SetPixel()?  Please tell us what UI lib you are coding against, WinForms, WPF, SilverLight...

Comment: Set/getpixel just too slow over web (images are dynamically created). Just using it through a .net web app, delivering an image through a generic handler.

Comment: I will check out color transformation matrix - thank you for suggestion..

Comment: @T1gg3rB0unC3: SetPixel is slow everywhere.  You can get a pointer to the image data by calling `Bitmap.LockBits`, which is quite fast.  if the matrix works for you go with that though.

Comment: @Slugart: I've (tentatively) added the *gdi+* tag, as that seems to be what everyone's talking about (*if* everyone's talking about the same API, that is). Without stating that, the question may be somewhat useless for future visitors.

Comment: @T1gg3rB0unC3, For future question avoid adding "thank you notes", instead up-vote good answers and accept one. Also whenever you say "better way" try to specify in which way something should be "better". I.e. in this question you probably want "faster"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at ImageAttributes.[SetRemapTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h9aaxdk.aspx)

[Another](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) example.

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing entire colors then you probably do not want to change them on a per pixel basis. There is a color transformation matrix that should allow you to change all pixles of a color in an image in a few lines of code, without having to loop through and manipulate each pixel of an image, which is horrendously slow.

See these links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tf7sa87(v=vs.71).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix.aspx

Comment: A transform is a great idea as long as the OP is ok with values overflowing and not being capped.  I remember trying this years (4 or more) ago and that was a problem for me, so I ended up simply calling `LockBits` and doing the work directly in memory.

Comment: I've never actually used the color matrix class myself, but have used various forms of lockbits or pinned arrays with great success.

Answer (score 0):

Use bitmap, BitBlt functionality. I show an example in [here](http://sohagbuet.wordpress.com/2013/11/03/alternative-of-setpixel-function/).